# What's the secret behind Wordpress' sitename.com/post-name type permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress

In `Wordpress` it is possible to have urls such as `sitename.com/post-title` although there exists no directory with name `post-name`.

I guess that `index.php` (or may be `404 page`) must be handling such kind of requests.

Anyone please explain the exact trick behind this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read about Mod Rewrite basics in [this page](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/). It's an Apache module that allows you to parse a request content and redirect it to a "real" page without changing browser address.

Let's say you have this:

```
 RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)?/?([0-9]+)?/?$ /index.php?p=$1&page=$2 [QSA]
```

With such a rewrite rule, a request address looking like:

```
www.mysite.com/post/10/2
```

Will be redirected to:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?p=10&page=2
```

And this is better on a point of view of both aesthetics [Search Engine Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization).

To be specific, in WordPress every request is redirected to index.php page which contains an internal "parser" of the request that loads the content depending on the parsing result.

नमस्ते!

Comment: Worth an upvote for the concept provided in the answer, but worth a down vote due to a link only answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: I'm upgrading my answer, give me time :P

Comment: Probably not the best method of answering. See this post on meta for the pros and cons: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Answer (score 2):

> I guess that index.php must be handling such kind
>   of requests.

Exactly.

They are redirecting all requests to index.php trough .htaccess rules. If you're thinking about adopting their solution in your own application - don't. Today there are better implementations of this technique. [Here](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router)'s an example.

Answer (score 1):

How it works:

mod_rewrite takes requests that match a certain parameter and can redirect them to other locations. In case of wordpress, all response (*) are accepted and transferred to the index.php page which has a standard router which splits the url i.e $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] and matches it against the stored configuration of url and loads the correct component (category, post, page etc)